# Facebook thumbnail shows correct size on fan page, but small size in timeline

Tags: facebook

I've updated my thumbnails to Facebook's lastest specifications (560x292px) but the thumbnail in the Facebook timeline will randomly show up as the previous smaller size, while showing correctly on my actual fan page.

I've run the Facebook linter and the correct thumb is shown in the og:image tag.

**Small size on timeline:**

[image: Smaller size in the timeline]

**Correct size on fan page:**

[image: Correct size on the fan page]

Comment: what exactly do you expect to see on timeline? I believe your screenshot is the way how timeline should look like... do you have any URLs with correct (as you think) image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#images you should use images that are 600 x 315  at the minimum to display link page posts with larger images.

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably a Facebook problem....I had some issues with it also.....

```
   Try doing this if you use google chrome:
        - Right click a white area, select "inspect element". 
        - Now when the tab opens at the bottom of the page, click and hold the refresh button, and some options will appear.
        - Select: Empty cache and hard reload. See if this happens again.
```

If you are using other browsers, try to delete cookies and clear cache, then login again and see if it works!

Good luck!